# Python 3, SQLAlchemy, MySQL. Incorrect syntax in INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, python-3.x

```
Engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://blah-blah-blah", encoding="utf-8")
Session = sessionmaker(bind = Engine)
ses = Session()
Meta = MetaData(bind = Engine, reflect = True)
PersonTable = Meta.tables["person"]

class Person(object):
   pass

mapper(Person, PersonTable)
APerson = Person("1111", "2222", "1.01.1980")
ses.add(APerson)
ses.commit()
```

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s)' at line 1") b'INSERT INTO person (`Name`, `OriginalName`, `DoB`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)' ('1111', '2222', '25.01.1980')

What is the %s? What do I wrong?

Python 3.1
SQLAlchemy 0.6.5
MySQL 5.1
Windows 7 Ultimate

Thank you.

Comment: its a C-style print thing, where each %s is supposed to sub for the string values '1111', '222' and '25.01.1980' respectively.  I don't know sqlalchemy in order to help you fix this

Comment: here is a similar question although more recent, hopefully it will have a useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732533/pyramid-python3-sqlalchemy-and-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You sqlalchemy commit is trying to issue an insert query that is not compatible with the schema. `near '%s, %s, %s)'` means your trying to insert invalid data. I can only speculate that it is because the date format - this is not the proper mysql date format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: I removed columb "DoB", but it did not help. The same error.

CREATE TABLE `Person`(
  `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `OriginalName` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Answer (score 0):

I migrated back to Python 2.7. Now it works fine.