# Pyramid, Python3, SQLAlchemy and MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I want Pyramid, Python3, SQLAlchemy and MySQL to play nice on a single machine. This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14282839/), but it was a long enough time ago that I'm hoping the answer has changed...

**Questions:**

*What driver works for getting a Python 3 Pyramid app to talk nicely to MySQL via SQLAalchemy? Is this even possible?*

I've gotten quite far in this project thinking it would be a simple thing to switch out databases, now I'm a bit stuck and downgrading to Python 2.7 is not something I want to have to go through. So my second question is:

*If there is no way to talk to MySQL nicely without downgrading, is there a database that Python 3 is ready for (besides SQLite)?*

Or lastly, *how would I overcome any of the problems mentioned in the 'Stuff I've Tried' section below?*

**Stuff I've Tried:**

*PyMySQL*

I have PyMySQL installed and I even got it to complain about incorrect passwords and a missing database so it's getting something right. But when I tried to initialize my database (using `initialize_foo_db`) everything went sour:

```
2013-02-06 17:18:31,282 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][MainThread] b'SELECT DATABASE()'
2013-02-06 17:18:31,282 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][MainThread] ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 719, in _do_get
return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)
File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/util/queue.py", line 137, in get
raise Empty
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../bin/initialize_mega_db", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('mega==0.0', 'console_scripts', 'initialize_mega_db')()
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/mega/mega/scripts/initializedb.py", line 46, in main
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 2567, in create_all
tables=tables)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2301, in _run_visitor
conn = self.contextual_connect(close_with_result=False)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2492, in contextual_connect
self.pool.connect(), 
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 224, in connect
return _ConnectionFairy(self).checkout()
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 387, in __init__
rec = self._connection_record = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 741, in _do_get
con = self._create_connection()
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 188, in _create_connection
return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 273, in __init__
pool.dispatch.first_connect.exec_once(self.connection, self)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/event.py", line 279, in exec_once
self(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/event.py", line 288, in __call__
fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 168, in first_connect
dialect.initialize(c)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 1999, in initialize
default.DefaultDialect.initialize(self, connection)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 177, in initialize
self._get_default_schema_name(connection)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 1964, in _get_default_schema_name
return connection.execute('SELECT DATABASE()').scalar()
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1449, in execute
params)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1628, in _execute_text
statement, parameters
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1691, in _execute_context
context)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 333, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/PyMySQL3-0.5-py3.2.egg/pymysql/cursors.py", line 108, in execute
query = query % escaped_args
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'tuple'
```

*oursql*

I tried installing oursql using `pip install -r file`

where file contains:

```
#oursql==0.9.3 but need special Python 3 build https://bugs.launchpad.net/oursql/+bug/1051512
https://launchpad.net/oursql/py3k/py3k-0.9.3/+download/oursql-0.9.3.zip
pyramid==1.3.4
```

And I got:

```
oursqlx/compat.h:13:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

*myconnpy*

This installs without error but I can't seem to find out what I should tell SQLAlchemy to look for. In the appropriate `settings.ini` file I have tried:

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+myconnpy://...
```

as well as a bunch of other things. Google is failing me on this one...

**UPDATE - a semblance of progress**

I've managed to install oursql build dependencies:

```
sudo aptitude install python-pip libmysqlclient-dev
```

I then downloaded oursql0.9.3 and ran:

```
setup.py install
```

The output was this:

```
cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file.
running install
running build
running build_ext
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/oursql.cpython-32mu.so -> /home/sheena/MegaCatalogue/env/lib/python3.2/site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing /path/to/virtualenv/foo/lib/python3.2/site-packages/oursql-0.9.3.egg-info
```

I opened a shell and apparently the module doesn't exist - it can't be imported anyway. But for some reason it is listed if I say help() then modules